# Order of two models that have belongsTo relation to a Model based on similar field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing a laravel **LMS** App and What I have described bellow is an simplified overview of that.

I have a table named `lesson` with these fields :

```
lesson_id
title
start_date
end_date
created_at
```

Each Lesson can have many **Units** and **Tests**. in fact Lesson model has a **OneToMany** relationship to Unit and Test Models.

**Unit** Model has these fields :

```
unit_id
title
content
created_at
lesson_id
.
.
.
```

And **Test** Model hase bellow fields :

```
test_id
title
description
created_at
lesson_id
.
.
.
```

And now for a specific Lesson, I want to list it's Units ans Tests in same order that a teacher(a specific user level in App) has created those like this :

**Lesson 1 :**
[image]

In addition, teacher can change order of placement of units and tests after creation via Drag and Drop functionality.

To fetch and list units and Tests of a Lesson with same creation order, I thought that can combine to Unit and Test Models  and use `createt_at` field.

But in this case, after teacher drags and Drops place of Units and Tests, What I do?

It occurred to me that I should use an `order` column in both unit and test table can be increased after each insertion. But I do not know how Can I change the `order` column on two separate table (unit and test) that are belongs to a Model(Lesson).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an order column, but then you always have to check if the item is a test or a unit.

```
(SELECT title, orderColumn, 'unit' as type FROM unit WHERE lession_id='2')
UNION
(SELECT title, orderColumn, 'test' as type FROM test WHERE lession_id='2')
ORDER BY orderColumn AS;
```

An alternative is that you create a connection table with lession_id, item_id, item_type and then you connect them with a JOIN depending on the item_type.

Comment: But how can I increase `orderColumn` on creation and update. I have `orderColumn` in two table.how to Initialize order of `units` and `tests`?

Comment: I changed the code slightly, now you also have a type and that allows you to run individual changes/edits (different FROM parameter).